# Delete databases from oracle 12c

Tags: oracle-12c

I want to delete multiple databases and its entries. These instances are not getting started. I want to delete data files also.

EDIT: I am thinking delete all data files. Please help on below concern.

**Shall I delete data files manually? Will it cause any problem to my working database instance?**

Comment: Could you provide us with additional information? What system is Oracle running on? (Windows or *nix) Are you able to run a GUI? Ever had a look at [DBCA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-F922EBB9-BA89-4A94-B89F-E3BB4BA14ACD.htm#ADMQS0231) (**D**ata**b**ase **C**onfiguration **A**ssistant)?

Comment: Thanks for a reply. Oracle is on windows system. On DBCA screen I can see the list of databases. As those instances are not getting started I am not able to login into it.

Comment: You are probably looking for `drop pluggable database`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and safest way to delete a database is using the RMAN `DROP DATABASE` command.

If on Linux, set up your ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID environment variables appropriately then start the database(s) using `startup mount exclusive restrict`.  Then drop it using RMAN's `DROP DATABASE`.  If you want to delete the backups/contents of the FRA as well, then use `DROP DATABASE INCLUDING BACKUPS`.

You could also use the GUI (DBCA - Database Creation Assistant), but this may be trickier depending on the environment.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Currently I am on windows system. As I said those databases are having some problems and will not start. Will 'start mount' command work?

Comment: It depends what the problems are.  Startup mount doesn't attempt to read the datafiles, only the controlfile(s), so depending what's wrong, it might work.

Answer (score -7):

Oracle has a Deinstall program. Go into the Oracle home of the database you want to remove. In the `bin` directory you will see a `deinstall.pl` (*nix) and a  `deinstall.bat` (Windows). Depending on which OS you are using start either one or the other.

This will delete everything except the inventory file. You will then need to go into the OS and remove the database entry from the `oratab` file.

Comment: This will remove the Oracle Home, which, given that the user states that they have other running databases, might not be the best idea.

Comment: This deinstall will remove Oracle binary, which may not be the user wants.